# How to make sure team members don't forget to do `git pull` before they start creating new branch to work?

Tags: git, github

Say a team of 4 shares a common Github repo hosted remotely. The repo helps process data from 20 different countries with 20 JSON config files for data processing instructions and a few common Python files used to transform the data.

Each team member is supposed to handle processing the data for 5 countries (thus, 20 countries total). Each team member is expected to update the JSON config files based on the incoming data's format (which varies every day) and push their changes to these JSON config files back to the central repo (so that others can substitute for her/his work when s/he is away). Individual team member may also modify the common Python script/file to update some data processing function whenever necessary.

Suppose I'm one of the team members, I will do this ever morning before I start my work on data transformation:

1. `git checkout main` -- the remote is pointing to our common Github repo
2. `git pull` -- to pull the latest updates that my coworkers have submitted previously to the main branch
3. `git checkout -b finland` -- to start working on data transformation for Finland data
4. `git add <files that I changed for finland data transformation>`
5. `git commit -m "Modified Finland data transform rules because blah blah blah"`
6. `git push origin finland` -- and make a pull request so that the reviewer of the repo can choose to integrate my changes as s/he sees relevant
7. `git push -d origin finland` -- once the reviewer approves my changes, I can delete the remote branch that I created earlier

The problem is sometimes I might forget to do `git pull` (step 2 above) on the `main` branch before I `checkout` a new branch to work on the code or the config files. I'm wondering if there's a way to force (or at least, remind) me to do `git pull` before I do a `git checkout -b <branch_name>`. I use Windows OS primarily, but if there's a script in Linux, I don't mind figuring out a way to adapt it on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answers!

Comment: There really isn't much harm in not pulling so long as what you do doesn't introduce a whole headache of conflicts with the main branch.  But if it does...then you'll have the pattern of needing to check out the branch etched into your memory since dealing with the merge conflicts is more painful than forgetting to merge the latest changes.

Comment: You could write a [post-checkout git hook](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) which outputs a little message?

Comment: You could always use the rebase method to merge in your Pull Requests, so the history gets linearized at that stage, assuming having a linear history is what you're after. Or you could have it in your PR acceptance protocol that the person who created the PR has to rebase it if they forgot to pull earlier. (I know, it's always good advice to avoid rebasing something that's been pushed, but here you're about to delete that branch anyway, since it only exists to create the PR.)

Comment: @Makoto Unfortunately, since the team touch (update) on the same code files for data transformation, the conflicts are unavoidable. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's an interesting tip. If there's no established way to force people to do a git pull (meaning if I don't receive any answer here in a few days), I'll implement the git hook that you suggested to at least remind folks that they must rebase with the main branch. Thank you.

Comment: @user1330974 Good idea to set a rule in the team to rebase before they create a pull request. I'm not much concerned about the history pollution as much as dealing with the conflicts when someone forgets to sync up with the main branch before they work on changes and submit a pull request. Thank you for your suggestion!